# Iterating to dynamically create objects from a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, if you want to create an object from a class you:

```
class person:
    pass

myObj=person()
```

But what if you want to create a multitude of objects? I always getting Name error:

```
In [1]: class person(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: for name in [khalid, majid]:
   ...:     name=person()
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-425dbd385d30> in <module>()
----> 1 for name in khalid, majid:
      2     name=person()
      3 

NameError: name 'khalid' is not defined
```

So, why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because when you write:

```
for name in [khalid, majid]:
```

Python tries to find the names `khalid` and `majid` so the objects they reference can also be referenced by the list. But those names haven't been assigned yet, hence `NameError`.

The best way to do this is to create a dictionary of objects, using `name` *strings* as keys:

```
people = {}
for name in ["khalid", "majid"]:
    people[name] = person()
```

You can also make the `name` an instance attribute:

```
class Person(object): # upper case for class names is conventional

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

and/or put the objects in a list:

```
people = []
for name in ["khalid", "majid"]:
    people.append(Person(name))
```